# In an orchestration pattern can we use data mappers in the orchestration layer?

Tags: microservices, datamapper

In a microservices architecture that uses the orchestration pattern is in the responsibilities of the orchestration layer (proxy) to do data mappings and prepare the data for the clients?

Answer (score 0):

Often, there is a layer (backend for frontend is a very similar pattern). That layer takes requests from customers, processes them and calls workflows on the orchestration engine/service. It is the front layer who takes the response and processes it before giving data back to the caller.

In addition to handling requests for callers, the front layer may also do extra processing, like authentication, authorization, throttling, etc.

At the end of the day, callers might not even know that orchestration is happening, as the internals of the system are hidden.